# null pointer exception after calling a method

Tags: java

this is withing the gui where i am calling the method.

```
seatNumber = x*6 + y+1;
isRserved = flight[h].reserve(seatNumber);
```

this is my method within another class

```
public boolean reserve (int seatNumber){
    int x = seatNumber / 6;
    int y = seatNumber % 6;

    if(seat[x][y] == true){
        isTaken = true;
        seat[x][y] = false;
    }
    return isTaken;
}
```

i keep getting a null pointer exception. is this how you call the method for this instance?

Comment: You understand we have no way of knowing where this null-pointer occurs?

Comment: please provide the stack trace of your NPE